# What does the word Regular or Linear mean with respect to formal grammars?

Tags: terminology, computer-science, formal-languages

I'm currently studying formal languages and automata.  We have covered the subjects of regular grammars and expressions, and right/left linear grammars.  I've been searching Google for a while now, but I can't seem to find a simple answer to the question of why they are called Regular or Linear.  I have found an abundance of explanations on how to identify if a grammar/language is regular or right/left linear, but that's not my question.  From what I have found Linear is in reference to the algorithmic parsing time of the grammar, O(n).  However, this is just my assumption, and I haven't found anything that definitively says this is so.

So, if anyone can please explain this and provided a link to a source it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually asking two interesting questions.

The term *regular* is an overloaded one in mathematics (think of [regular element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_element), [regular semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_semigroup),  [regular space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space), [regular scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_scheme), [regular conditional probablity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability), just to name a few), but in computer science, it mainly refers to [*regular expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [*regular languages*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), introduced by Kleene [1] in 1951.

The term *linear* refers to [linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation), but in a [noncommutative context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar). Consider for instance
the right-linear grammar
\begin{align}
S_1 &\to aS_2 + 1\\
S_2 &\to bS_1 
\end{align}
It can be interpreted as a system of linear equations over the [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) $\mathcal{P}(A^*)$ of languages on the alphabet $A$. A solution of this linear system is a pair of languages $(L_1, L_2)$ satisfying $L_1 = aL_2 + 1$ and $L_2 = bL_1$ (here $+$ stands for union and $1$ is the language reduced to the empty word). In this case, the unique solution is $\bigl((ab)^*, b(ab)^*\bigr)$.

[1] Kleene, Stephen C. (1951). Shannon, Claude E.; McCarthy, John (eds.). [Representation of Events in Nerve Nets and Finite Automata](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_memoranda/2008/RM704.pdf). Automata Studies. Princeton University Press. pp. 3–42.

Comment: Hi J-E Pin, thank you very much for your answer, and the link!  My favorite quote from the Kleene paper:" "Regular events" defined: We shall describe a class of events which we will call "regular events." (We would welcome any suggestions as to a more descriptive term.*)"